# 'Site Contents' page not loading - JS error in console

Tags: sharepoint-online, error

I'm experiencing an issue when accessing the 'Site Contents' of all of my sites/collections. The URL at the root site collection is: https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx.

Nothing loads, and I receive the following error message in the console: 
[image]

Has anyone had a similar issue of SPO production js files throwing syntax errors?

Comment: If this is not a customization doing this then log a support ticket with Microsoft. They push updates all the time, and maybe your tenant got a broken one.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to bypass the main contents page - try going to `_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx` and see if that works.

It's basically 'god mode' for the site.